# jQuery - how to exclude a DOM element from executing an animation?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with that HTML code. The most parent div (class='question-cont') executes an animation (jQuery `slideToggle()`) But, I if I click on the `IPSUM` text, that animation is also being executed. How to exclude the `div.answer-data-container` from executing that animation ?

```
<div class='question-cont'>
    <div class='question-toggle-header'>
        <div class='left question-container'>
           <label class='label-none orange-font left'>LOREM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div class='left answer-data-container slider'>
        <div class='q-text'>
            <label class='label-none left'>IPSUM</label>
        </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
```

Comment: Please add your jQuery code to your question.

Comment: Bind your event to `.question-toggle-header`, not `.question-cont`.

Answer (score 2):

Because IPSUM is a part of `question-cont` so when you click on IPSUM you also click on `question-cont`. Why don't you use `question-toggle-header` instead of `question-cont` to trigger the `slideToggle`